# Are hooks or global hotkeys possible on Nokia's Series 40 at all?

Tags: hook, nokia, series-40

Is there a way other then being Nokia to write an application for global hotkeys/hooks on Series 40 (6th edition)? The only way to add user code appears to be Java, and the Java sandbox does not seem to allow multitasking with other phone applications.

My specific goal is to 'fix' the issue with several Nokia feature phones that don't include dedicate volume keys, but do include a pair of extra application shortcut keys which are only used on the home screen - remap these keys to control the volume from any application, if possible.

Comment: Which phones are you working with?

Comment: For physical testing I have an unbranded Nokia C3-00. The same application shortcut keys (defaulted to applications like contacts, mail, media player and GPS) appear on a number of 2010 vintage Nokia feature phones running S40 6th edition, both QWERTY and flip.

Comment: You can reconfigure the shortcuts from the settings and assign it to be the volume app.

Answer (score 0):

For Series40 Background MIDlets are enabled for operator and manufacturer domains only. Even if you would have a background midlet, you would need the help of Series40 internal APIs to catch the keys before the application that has the current key focus